# How to pretty format json data that is returned from a curl request?

Tags: javascript, php, curl

I created a curl request from url http://datos.labplc.mx/movilidad/vehiculos/436per.json using php in a age of our site. It is working and it is echoing the following data even without having to echo it. We are starting with `curl_init` and finishing with `curl_close` if you need to know.

```
{
  "consulta": {
    "placa": "430PER",
    "tenencias": {
      "placa": "430PER",
      "adeudos": "2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016",
      "tieneadeudos": "1"
    },
    "infracciones": [
      {
        "folio": "04102237388",
        "fecha": "2010-03-11",
        "situacion": "No pagada",
        "motivo": "POR ESTACIONARSE EN  LAS V&Iacute;AS PRIMARIAS",
        "fundamento": "Art&iacute;culo: 12, Fracci&oacute;n: I, Parrafo: , Inciso: ",
        "sancion": "10 unidades de cuenta "
      },
      {
        "folio": "04092079661",
        "fecha": "2009-06-19",
        "situacion": "No pagada",
        "motivo": "POR CERRAR U OBSTRUIR LA CIRCULACI&Oacute;N EN LA V&Iacute;A P&Uacute;BLICA CON VEH&Iacute;CULOS, PLUMAS, REJAS O CUALQUIER OTRO OBJETO.",
        "fundamento": "Art&iacute;culo: 14, Fracci&oacute;n: VII, Parrafo: , Inciso: ",
        "sancion": "10 unidades de cuenta "
      }
    ],
    "verificaciones": "error"
  }
}
```

My question:

How can I show the returned data in an HTML table so it looks clean and readable?

Comment: what have to tried to convert that data to html
you can use Datatable.js

Comment: What have you already tries?

Comment: Not sure what to try. I am stuck with the mentioned returned result.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `json_decode()`. so it returns the  json into array and then you can use array and populate data in your html table

Comment: I can follow the json_decode() instructions but after that how do i set it as a table.can you give me precise instructions? would be well appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I mostly do this by adding the **"pre"** tag

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($JSON);
echo "</pre>";
```

EDIT IN HTML

```
$string = file_get_contents("http://datos.labplc.mx/movilidad/vehiculos/436per.json"); 
$json = json_decode($string, true);

$lines = $json['consulta']['infracciones'];

echo "<table>";
foreach($lines as $line)
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $line['folio'] . "</tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $line['fecha'] . "</tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $line['situacion'] . "</tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $line['motivo'] . "</tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $line['fundamento'] . "</tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $line['sancion'] . "</tr>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: yes but how do I make it print a table with the returned data looking pretty, not like code. thanks

Comment: `$string = file_get_contents("http://datos.labplc.mx/movilidad/vehiculos/436per.json");
$lines = $json['consulta']['infracciones'];

echo "<table>";
foreach($lines as $line)
{
 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td>" . $line['folio'] . "</tr>";
 echo "<td>" . $line['fecha'] . "</tr>";
 echo "<td>" . $line['situacion'] . "</tr>";
 echo "<td>" . $line['motivo'] . "</tr>";
 echo "<td>" . $line['fundamento'] . "</tr>";
 echo "<td>" . $line['sancion'] . "</tr>";
 echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";`